# In windows forms application, which location is recommended to store license details - HKLM or HKCU

Tags: windows, winforms, registry

I'm developing a windows forms application and want to activate the application and store the license details somewhere in the registry. I want to understand what is the recommended location to store the license details of windows forms application.

Is it HKLM or HKCU?

And will the application license details get stored at both locations if the user does not have the admin rights?

Comment: They are quite different, HKCU is linked to the current user whereas HKLM is linked to the machine itself (i.e. all users).  Which is appropriate depends on your licensing model, i.e. per user or per machine.

Comment: Will user require admin rights to store the license details under HKCU

Comment: No, not for HKCU as it belongs to the current user.